# is it possible to block users from using api operations in azure api management?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I wrote below code for blocking user from group dev, from using an api operation. I would like to know if there is a method for blocking users in a group from accessing a particular method like put, delete and only allow user from a group to use get method?

```
<choose>
    <when condition="@(context.User.Groups.Any(g => g.Name == "dev"))">
        <return-response>
            <set-status code="403" reason="Unauthorized" />
            <set-body>Users in group dev do not have access to this method.</set-body>
        </return-response>
    </when>
</choose>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <set-variable name="isAccessible" value="@(context.User.Groups.Any(g => g.Name == "dev") && context.Request.Method==PUT)" />

 <choose>
       <when condition="@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<bool>("isAccessible"))">
            <return-response>
                 <set-status code="403" reason="Unauthorized" />
                <set-body>Users in group dev do not have access to this method.</set-body>
            </return-response>
         </when>
     </choose>
```

PS: Not Tested

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'validate-jwt' policy and Allow/restrict the access based on method called. Users will present the JWT token while calling the API, you can use operation level policy or API level policy(based on method check) and verify the JWT token claim.

You can refer microsoft documentation here for use of policy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#ValidateJWT